# getting row/column of dynamic 2d array element

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

I am currently using the following code to get the current row and column of an element in a 2D int array:

```
const int num_rows = 5;
const int num_columns = 7;

int a[num_rows][num_columns];

int *p = &a[2][4];

int row = (p - &a[0][0]) / num_columns;
int col = (p - &a[row][0]);
```

This works fine but now I need to change the code to take the number of rows and columns as a parameter. As far as I know, this means I need to create the 2D array dynamically:

```
int** ary = new int*[sizeX]; 

for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; ++i) 
    ary[i] = new int[sizeY];
```

If I create the 2D array this way, the above code to find the row/column breaks. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 int *ary = new int [sizeX * sizeY]; // allocate memory for the 2d array

 for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; ++I)
     for(j = 0; j < sizeY; ++j) 
          ary[i * sizeY + j] = 0;

  // to get the value of collumn c and row r: use ary[c * sizeY + r];
```

Comment: I think that I can make it work this way. It's a little more bookkeeping since it's really a 1D array but I guess it's the best option for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int row = (p - &a[0][0]) / num_columns;
> int col = (p - &a[row][0]);
> ```

It's a very good idea to stay way from pointer arithmetic.  Don't do this! You are essentially subtracting the pointer and divide that number by num_columns, and that number will be random.

If you want to get the row/column of an element, search the array one element at a time.

```
for(int row=0; row<num_rows; ++row) {
   for(int column=0; column<num_columns; ++column) {
      if (a[row][column] == element) {
         // we got it!
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The OP wanted to get `row` `column` from a pointer `p` , so maybe it should be `if (a[row]+column == p)`

Comment: The OP wanted the dimensions of the 2d array variable. This only works if 'a' has a static dimension.

Comment: Why will that number be random? The difference between the pointers will give the number of elements between said pointers and dividing by the number of elements in a column will give the current row since integer division truncates the remainder. Did I misunderstand what you meant?

Comment: When you do multiple 'new', the memory allocated for each new is not guaranteed to be contiguous. After your loop there, ary[1] - ary[0] will not return sizeY. So, are you trying to get row/col of an element or the dimension of a 2d array variable?